# Java build error "returns unavailable type"

Tags: java, build, compiler-errors, return

I am in confusion related to this build issue.
Following cases are build successfully.

**case 1**

`

```
public Insets getOpticalInsets() {
 System.out.println(" hello ");
 return Insets.NONE;
}
```

`

**case 2**

`

```
public Insets getOpticalInsets() { 
{
 return Insets.NONE;
}
}
```

`

but the following case fails and gives the error message as " returns unavailable type Insets"

**failed case**

`

```
public Insets getOpticalInsets() { 
{
 System.out.println(" hello ");
 return Insets.NONE;
}
}
```

`

I have searched about similar errors but could not find anything useful. Can somebody explain me what is actually the error.

Complete Log message

frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java:601: error 110: Method android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getOpticalInsets returns unavailable type Insets

Source file:

```
`

package android.graphics.drawable;

import android.graphics.Insets;
import android.os.Trace;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.NinePatch;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.StateSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.util.Xml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Arrays;


public abstract class Drawable {
    private static final Rect ZERO_BOUNDS_RECT = new Rect();

    private int[] mStateSet = StateSet.WILD_CARD;
    private int mLevel = 0;
    private int mChangingConfigurations = 0;
    private Rect mBounds = ZERO_BOUNDS_RECT;  
    private WeakReference<Callback> mCallback = null;
    private boolean mVisible = true;

    private int mLayoutDirection;


    private String mImagePath;



    public Insets getOpticalInsets() {        
            {
                System.out.println(" hello ");
                return Insets.NONE;
            }
    }



}
```

`

Comment: what is `Insects.NONE`? An Enum?

Comment: Paste the complete code of the non-compiling class (from the package statement to the last curly brace, and the exact and complete error you get. The last snippet is identical to the first one,e xcept for the additional curly brace. Without more context, we can't explain anything.

Comment: I have only given the relevant part of the source code since the whole file is quite large to fit in here. In the original source code only return statement is present inside the function body. I have only added the print statement and curly braces, and please don't ask why i am adding those additional braces, it is required.

Comment: Insets.NONE is itself an object as written in the android.graphics.Insets source file.
public static final Insets NONE = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);